# how to get RSS or ATOM feed url from blogurl

Tags: c#, url, blogs, feed

how i can get feed url (RSS Or ATOM) from blog url 
ex:- http://anirudhagupta.blogspot.com/
So how i can get his feed dynamically by c#

i say that how i can get blog's feedurl by using Regex and c#

Comment: I think the answer about finding the RSS feed URL in the link rel is the answer that should be accepted. The answer you marked accepted shows how to load and parse an RSS feed but I believe your question was about finding that feed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Rss feeds can vary with what you specifically want to look at, but for blogspot it's usually

*blogname*/feeds/posts/default
ie. http://anirudhagupta.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default

If you're using VS 2008, you can use the SyndicationFeed object to read both RSS and ATOM feeds. (I assume this is what you want to do when you say "get his feed dynamically")

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(feedUriString);
SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
{
//your code for rendering each item
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.aspx
http://jimleonardo.blogspot.com/2009/02/jimleocom-is-back-up-some-how-to.html

Comment: you are right but i say that how i can get feedurl means to say that dynamically EX:- i have a 1 lac blogs then how i can get all blogs 'feedurl

Answer (score 6):

When you visit the root page of the site, ie. http://myblog.com/ you should find a link attribute in the head, something like:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="MyBlog RSS Feed" href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/MyBlog" />
```

Now, no site is guaranteed to have that link in the head, but if they want that little rss logo to show up in firefox or internet explorer when users visit their site, they probably have added that line.  Wordpress does it by default.

Note: My examples are just fictitious examples, not real sites.  But just look at the source of a few blogs you know, and you should see a link tag like this.

Comment: Re: Note: Remember RFC 2606 § 2, example.com and others are set aside for examples. http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2606#section-2

Comment: Thanks brian, I'll remember that for next time.  Maybe if I had conformed to rfc 2606, I would have received the check ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `WebRequest` to read the data, and from the `Headers` you will know the content-type, if the `content-type` is `text/xml`, you just use XmlReader to read it, but if the `content-type` is `text/html`, you may need to do more work.
For example, the address is http://myblog.com, not http://myblog.com/feed/ that you want. So you need find the rss address from the default page's link tag, the link tag is like this:
`<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS" href="/rss"/ >`
To find the rss link, you can use `Microsoft HTML Object Library`, get the link tag, then use `obj.getAttribute("href")` method to get the relative address.